How to Ensure Consistency When a Worker Process Reads Configurations During Leader Update in ZooKeeper?
I'm going through ZooKeeper: Wait-free coordination for Internet-scale systems. In section 2.3 ZooKeeper Guarantees, authors have detailed how below scenario is handled. Though I believe Justification provided in paragraph two of section 2.3 is not complete.
Assume a scenario where master node needs to update configurations in zookeeper. For this the master node need to remove 'ready' znode. Any worker node verifies the presence of 'ready' znode before reading any configuration. When a new master node needs to update configuration, it deletes the 'ready' znode and then updates the configuration and add 'ready' znode back again. With the technique, no worker server will read the configuration while it is being updated.
However, there could be scenario in which worker node reads the 'ready' znode, starts reading the configuration. While worker node is reading the configuration, the master node, in order to update configuration, delete 'ready' znode and starts updating the configuration. Now we are in the scenario where the configurations are being updated while a worker node halfway thorough reading the configuration. Given this is very real possibility, how are these conditions handled.
